# Can I perform a count distinct query on values selected from a listbox?

Tags: ms-access-2003

I have a select distinct query that works find on selected fields from a listbox. However I would like it to be a count distinct and I can't seem to get the code right. Below is my working code for select distinct. Thanks in advance for any assistance I've searched for count distinct questions but I don't see any specific to listbox selections.

```
Private Sub CmdDistinctVal_Click()
Dim cn1 As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs1 As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd1 As New ADODB.Command
Dim varItem As Variant
Dim aFields() As aArray
Dim NumRows As Integer
Dim NumFields As Integer
Dim colcount As Integer
Dim colwidths As String
Dim strRow As String
Dim cnt1 As Integer
Dim cnt2 As Integer

'On Error GoTo Err_ CmdDistinctVal_Click

'cmd1.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection

Me.DistinctResultsFldVal.RowSource = ""

ReDim aFields(50)
For cnt1 = 1 To 50
ReDim aFields(cnt1).fValue(6000)
Next

NumRows = 0
colcount = 0

For Each varItem In Me!ResultsFieldList.ItemsSelected
    colcount = colcount + 1
    aFields(colcount).fName = Me!ResultsFieldList.ItemData(varItem)
    NumFields = 0

    rs1.Open "SELECT DISTINCT " & Me!ResultsFieldList.ItemData(varItem) & " 
FROM [Results Report]", CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic


If rs1.RecordCount > NumRows Then NumRows = rs1.RecordCount
strRow = strRow & Me!ResultsFieldList.ItemData(varItem) & ";"

While Not rs1.EOF
    NumFields = NumFields + 1
    If NumFields > NumRows Then
        NumRows = NumFields
    End If

    aFields(colcount).fValue(NumFields) = rs1(0) & ""


    rs1.MoveNext
Wend
rs1.Close
Next varItem
strRow = Left(strRow, Len(strRow) - 1)

Me.DistinctResultsFldVal.ColumnCount = colcount
Me.DistinctResultsFldVal.ColumnWidths = Mid(colwidths, 2)
Me.DistinctResultsFldVal.AddItem (strRow)

For cnt1 = 1 To NumRows

strRow = ""
For cnt2 = 1 To colcount
    If aFields(cnt2).fValue(cnt1) = "" Then
        strRow = strRow & ";"
    Else
        strRow = strRow & aFields(cnt2).fValue(cnt1) & ";"
    End If
Next
strRow = Left(strRow, Len(strRow) - 1)
Me.DistinctResultsFldVal.AddItem (strRow)

Next

'Err_ CmdDistinctVal_Click:
    'MsgBox "All null values were found in one or more of your selected fields"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is this a repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11970982/77335 ?

Comment: No, I'm trying to change the query results so they include a count. That was a question in regards to the Select Distinct query timing out if there were too many distinct values.

Comment: Since Access doesn't support `Count(DISTINCT some_field)`, we do the distinct row selection with a subquery, then do the counting from the parent query.  Here is an example from yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720169/count-distinct-query-ms-access/12720480#12720480  However, I'm getting lost trying to understand your code, so don't know how to apply a similar approach to your question.

Comment: `Dim aFields() As aArray` That declaration throws a compile error for me.  What the heck is `aArray`? A custom class?

Comment: HansUp--yes, aArray is a module (code below). Please excuse me for leaving that part out.
    Option Compare Database
    Type aArray
        fName As String
        fValue() As String
    End Type